# DB2 - AUTONOMOUS Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I would like to write an AUTONOMOUS stored procedure (native). I'm using the DB2 database (V11.01)

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LOG (IN p_field1  char(2)
                          ,IN p_field2  varchar(50)
                          ,IN p_field3  varchar(50)
                          ,IN p_field4  varchar(3926) )
      VERSION V1
      ISOLATION LEVEL CS
    WLM ENVIRONMENT FOR DEBUG MODE WLMENV1
      RESULT SETS 0
      LANGUAGE SQL
    ALLOW DEBUG MODE 
      AUTONOMOUS
  BEGIN
    ...
    ...
  END
```

I'm using IBM DATA STUDIO 4.1.1 and I get the following error:

Creazione di procedura memorizzata restituzioni

> SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601. XXXXX.SP_LOG: 11: ILLEGAL SYMBOL
>   "". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: FOR.
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60 XXXXX.SP_LOG -
>   Distribuzione per il debug non riuscita. XXXXX.SP_LOG - Rollback
>   completato correttamente.

If you have any recommendations, I'd love to hear them!

Thanks :)

Comment: What platform?  zOS or LUW?

Comment: the stored must work in both platform (z/os and luw). step 1: run it on z/os platform

Comment: It seems to be a BUG of IBM DATA STUDIO: 

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1IT26018. 

Now I try to install version 4.1.3 and update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I found the issue.

This is a bug of IBM Data Studio (IT26018 - AUTONOMOUS KEYWORD IS NOT CONSIDERED AS A VALID KEYWORD FOR DB2 ZOSV11 AND V12 IN DS.4.1.3 - [For more information click here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1IT26018).

Here's how I solved it:

1. I downloaded the new version (IBM DATA STUDIO 4.1.3) - [Link](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-data-studio)
2. Installed the new version using IBM INSTALLATION MANAGER
3. I downloaded the FIX - [Link](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?product=ibm%2FInformation%20Management%2FIBM%20Data%20Studio&fixids=DS_413_APAR3_v20181011_0430&source=SAR&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Information%20%25%2020Management)
4. Installed the FIX (Instructions are included in the .ZIP file (open the "Hotfix Guide.pdf" file)